# Remove all blank lines from list python

Tags: python

I have the following results set as a variable.  I need to remove all blank lines before I can make it a dictionary.  What is a simple command I can run on a variable to remove all blank lines that may be contained in that variable.  Below is an example of the output of my variable:

```
DeviceName = device1
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = west
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.1
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None


DeviceName = device2
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = None
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.2
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None
```

There is also a blank space at the beginning.  I have tried a few different ways, but they only seem to remove the first blank line. I need to remove any and all blank lines that might appear in my results.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure but this may be what you want:

```
>>> text = '''DeviceName = device1
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = west
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.1
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None


DeviceName = device2
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = None
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.2
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None'''
>>> text = '\n'.join(line for line in text.splitlines() if line)
```

But it would be much better to just ignore the blanks lines as you create your dictionary, using a generator expression:

```
>>> lines = (line for line in text.splitlines() if line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txt = """DeviceName = device1
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = west
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.1
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None


DeviceName = device2
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = None
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.2
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None"""

print('\n'.join([i for i in txt.split('\n') if i]))
```

Output:

```
DeviceName = device1
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = west
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.1
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None
DeviceName = device2
ClientName = myclient
RegionName = None
PrimaryIP = 1.1.1.2
OsVersionName = Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise
AccessMethod = None
AccessIP = None
Port = None
```

Comment: I have no clue, but for some reason that doesn't work for me.  When I copy your code exactly it works, but when I add it in to my code that I am using, it outputs with the spaces there.
Before I end up with the output above, I am doing a few different replaces and one strip to end up with the output above.  Is there anyway that those are somehow affecting the string and not letting it be changed later?